# How to generate comma separated numbers in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

For example for numbers from 7 to 12, I need 7,8,9,10,11,12

This is for splitting csv files using [csvcut](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html). it requires me to list the column indices.

For example if I need to cut columns from 70-80, I need to write:

`csvcut -c 70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80 my_input.csv > my_output.csv`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `seq` with the `-s` option to set the separator:

```
$ seq -s, 7 12
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

and for your example:

```
csvcut -c `seq -s, 70 80` my_input.csv > my_output.csv
```